# Appending elements to DOM with indentation/spacing

Tags: javascript, html, append, spacing, appendchild

[**Here is an example**](http://jsbin.com/ilAsAki/4/edit). Check the console for the result. The first two `div`s (not appended; above the `<script>` in the console) have the proper spacing and indention. However, the second two `div`s do not show the same formatting or white space as the original even though they are completely the same, but appended.

For example the input

```
var newElem = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(newElem);
var another = document.createElement('div');
newElem.appendChild(another);
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Gives the output

```
<div><div></div></div>
```

When I want it to look like

```
<div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to generate the proper white space between appended elements and retain that spacing when obtaining it using `innerHTML` (or a possible similar means)? I need to be able to visually display the hierarchy and structure of the page I'm working on.

I have tried appending it within an element that is in the actual HTML but it has the same behavior

I'd be okay with doing it using text nodes and line breaks as lincolnk suggested, but it needs to affect dynamic results, meaning I cannot use the same `.createTextNode('   </br>')` because different elements are in different levels of the hierarchy

No jQuery please

Comment: I think you're looking for `innerText` or `textContent` (FF) ...?

Comment: @joshstrike No, I'm not. I updated the question to make it more clear in what I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're asking to be able to append elements to the DOM, such that the string returned from `document.body.innerHTML` will be formatted with indentation etc. as if you'd typed it into a text editor, right?

If so, something like this might work:

```
function indentedAppend(parent,child) {
    var indent = "",
        elem = parent;

    while (elem && elem !== document.body) {
        indent += "  ";
        elem = elem.parentNode;
    }

    if (parent.hasChildNodes() && parent.lastChild.nodeType === 3 && /^\s*[\r\n]\s*$/.test(parent.lastChild.textContent)) {
        parent.insertBefore(document.createTextNode("\n" + indent), parent.lastChild);
        parent.insertBefore(child, parent.lastChild);
    } else {
        parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n" + indent));
        parent.appendChild(child);
        parent.appendChild(document.createTextNode("\n" + indent.slice(0,-2)));
    }

}
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/ilAsAki/28/edit

I've not put too much thought into it, so you might need to play with it, but it's a starting point at least.

Also, i've assumed an indentation of 2 spaces as that's what you seemed to be using.

Oh, and you'll obviously need to be careful when using this with a `<pre>` tag or anywhere the CSS is set to maintain the whitespace of the HTML.

Comment: +1 Very nice, this is what I was thinking would be the way to do it but was unable to create it properly myself (using `"\n"` makes it easier than what I was trying). One small thing: when appending an element to the same level as an existing element, there is an unnecessary empty line. Is there an easy way to remove this? [Example](http://jsbin.com/ilAsAki/12/edit)

Comment: Lovely, thanks a lot! If no one comes up with a cleaner solution (likely meaning using the default append somehow) then the bounty will be yours

Comment: @Zeaklous hey, after getting some sleep, i've updated my answer to use `.appendChild`

Comment: Again, there is unneeded blank space in the second level when there are sibling elements. Removing the third `appendChild` line removes it, but it also removes a line break necessary on the last child of a level [(example here)](http://jsbin.com/ilAsAki/19/edit). I would fix this using a simple check for `nextSibling` and if its null then give it the line break, but since each element is appended after the other this wouldn't work. Would I have to do the check after all elements are appended or can you think up a better fix?

Comment: Using `/\r?\n|\r/g.test(...` to detect line breaks removed the blank lines but messed up some of the indentation, [example here](http://jsbin.com/ilAsAki/20/edit). Any idea why?

Comment: @Zeaklous ok man, updated the answer with a solution. Again, it's probably not fool-proof but it should hopefully be reasonably solid.

Comment: I believe it works as I would like for it to, I have to change the structure of some of my other code in the actual project to fit to make sure. Thanks for all of the work you put into it! On a side note I like several of your answers on other people's questions, good work! I wish SO had a way to "add friends" of sort

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.createTextNode()` to add a string directly.

```
var ft = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(ft);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode('   '));
var another = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(another);
console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

Comment: Is there a way to dynamically format each line based on its hierarchy like is done on elements placed into the `body` by the HTML? I updated my question to make that more clear